# Specifying an absolute pathname to matchImageSnapshot

Tags: cypress, screenshot

I am using the cy.matchImageSnapshot package for cypress to do screen shots. Everything is working great except I am trying to specify an absolute pathname to place the screen shots. (e.g. "customSnapshotsDir: "/ScreenCaps") But no matter what I specify it is always relative to where the test is running. I've even tried "customSnapshotsDir: "C:/ScreenCaps" but again it attempts to create a directory that is relative. Is there anyway to specify an absolute pathname?